# App crashing. KeyException?

Tags: windows-phone-7, stack-trace

I get crash reports from my app. I really don't understand what the problem is. It never
crashes with me... What can be the problem? From the app hub error message:

`0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                            19

1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                  436488

2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                  386545

3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                  540936

4                          TransitionStub                                                0

5                          System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException                  52

6                          System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary 2.get_Item              136

7                          System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.get_Item    80

8                          ScheduledTaskAgent1.ScheduledAgent.OnInvoke                   660

9                          Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledTaskAgent.Invoke           856

10                         .AgentRequest.Invoke                                          764

11                         Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentDispatcher.InvocationThread    196

12                         System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStartHelper               132

13                         System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context             80

14                         System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run                         324

15                         System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStartHelper               168

16       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                  429164

17       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                  310125

18       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                  310319

19       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                  305995"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the BackgroundAgent is trying to load an item from the IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings that doesn't exist. Check in your ScheduledTaskAgent1.ScheduledAgent.OnInvoke method.

1/ First check the existence of the key using the "IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains" method before retrieving it

2/ If the key does not exist, act accordingly

For instance, if you're doing:

```
somevalue = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["setting"];
```

Then "setting" is the key the error message is referring too. Replace your code by:

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("setting"))
{
    somevalue = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["setting"];
}else
{
    // set somevalue to its default value
}
```